# How to create a DbContext instance of the specified database type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know that the default return here is the SQL Server database type, but I need the MySQL database type, the problem is to create a `DbContext` instance of the specified database type?

Of course, I know that it can also be created by specifying the `connectionName`, but the database connection string is encrypted and the string needs to be decrypted

The pseudo code is as follows:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    static string mysqlConn = ReadConnectionString(); //Get the encrypted MySQL connection string

    public MyDbContext() : base(mysqlConn)
    {
        // Even if I want to modify the connection string in this way, nor will it throw a connection string malformed exception
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = DecryptConnectionString(mysqlConn);
    }
}
```

Comment: What framework and version do you use ?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 + EntityFramework 6

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's about what I expected, few of my questions can be answered.

Although I am not too familiar with EntityFramework, by looking at the source code of DbContext, I can almost certainly determine that this is a design flaw, it lacks a constructor like this:

```
Public DbContext(string connectionString, string providerName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and found .Net framework 4.5 needs additional attribute on DbContext class to use MySql as below

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MySqlContext : DbContext
{
...
}
```